# image converted from pdf file with Imagick got grey background

Tags: php, imagick

I'm trying to convert a pdf file to image with imagick in php. The script works fine but the image created has a grey background like if the background of the pdf file is removed

```
$srcimg = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/files/pdf_canevas/doc1.pdf'; 

$targetimg = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/files/pdf_canevas/doc1.jpeg'; 

$im = new imagick();
$im->setResolution(150, 150);
$im->readImage($srcimg);
$im->setImageFormat('jpeg');
$im->setImageCompression(imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG); 
$im->setImageCompressionQuality(100);
$im->writeImage($targetimg);

$im->clear();
$im->destroy();
```

this is an exemple of background i got on the conversion image
[image]

image output
[image]

Comment: Q: What exactly do you mean? Does the .pdf contain a graphical image (e.g. a photo), and does any of the image display correctly?  Q: Have you tried with other - completely different .pdfs?  Q: Have you tried different output formats (for example, a png instead of a jpeg)? Q: Can you post a screenshot of the original .pdf, and the resulting .jpeg?

Comment: yes the initial pdf file contains like a special background . but this is not concerning all the pdf files for many pdf i tried with i got perfect image version for the other pdf even if i change the format to png i got a grey background on the image

Comment: Try adding `$im->setBackgroundColor('#ffffff);` before `$im->readimage`